# Rails 3 / PhoneGap: Converting a Rails app into an Phonegap Android app?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails

I have a site built on top of Rails. In essence, I want to release a Android app and I think Phonegap is a good solution.

What would be the easiest way to get something like this done? I'm new to PhoneGap and would like to know how this can be achieved.

Is there a way to achieve this? Would be really helpful if someone can explain this in depth or share link/URL for tutorial/s.

Answer (score 4):

We added a phone-gap version of our site recently.
Those are the steps we took:

1. Built a single page mobile app using backbone.js - backbone is lightweight which is important on mobile traffic.
   see:
   http://railscasts.com/episodes/323-backbone-on-rails-part-1
   http://railscasts.com/episodes/325-backbone-on-rails-part-2
2. All the forms should go to a full path url (e.g. http://example.com/accounts instead of /accounts)
3. Use a deployment script to dump your html, js, css and images to a single folder
4. Use Phonegap to wrap the output of 3

Comment: Can you elaborate on #3? Are you talking about some kind of custom rake task? Or something like `wget -r` to simply query your Rails server?

Comment: currently we just use shell script with a bunch of curl commands with some simple text manipulations to change the urls.
I guess it makes sense to wrap it all in a rake task when the tasks pile up.